# Trying to make these 2 arrays store the input sum in a 3rd list

Tags: java, arrays, calculator

I'm studying java, and I'm trying to make this thing work.

I made 3 arrays in java, 2 of which accepts input, with 10 elements each.

The sum of the contents of list1 and list2 should be stored in list 3, and display the results

This is my code (really messy,sorry)

```
public class List2 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
    int list1[]=new int[10];
    int list2[]=new int[10];
    int list3[]=new int[10];
    int i, sum=0, num1=0, num2=0;
    String input=" ";

    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            list1[i]=0;
            list2[i]=0;
            list3[i]=0;
        }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.print("Input value for list1[" + i + "] = ");

            try{
                input=in.readLine();
            }catch(IOException e){}
            num1=Integer.parseInt(input);
            list1[i]=num1;
           }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "] = "+list1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.print("Input value for list2[" + i + "] = ");

            try{
                input=in.readLine();
            }catch(IOException e){}
            num2=Integer.parseInt(input);
            list2[i]=num2;
           }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "] = "+list2[i]);
    }    
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        sum = list1[i]+list2[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("list3[" + sum + "]="+"list1[" + list1[i] + "]+"+"list2[" + list2[i] + "]");
    }
    }
}
```

To my dismay, only the last input of list1 and list2 gets displayed in all of list3. These are the results

```
**Input value for list1[0] = 1
Input value for list1[1] = 2
Input value for list1[2] = 3
Input value for list1[3] = 4
Input value for list1[4] = 1
Input value for list1[5] = 2
Input value for list1[6] = 3
Input value for list1[7] = 1
Input value for list1[8] = 41
Input value for list1[9] = 2
list[0] = 1
list[1] = 2
list[2] = 3
list[3] = 4
list[4] = 1
list[5] = 2
list[6] = 3
list[7] = 1
list[8] = 41
list[9] = 2
Input value for list2[0] = 4
Input value for list2[1] = 1
Input value for list2[2] = 2
Input value for list2[3] = 1
Input value for list2[4] = 1
Input value for list2[5] = 3
Input value for list2[6] = 1
Input value for list2[7] = 1
Input value for list2[8] = 1
Input value for list2[9] = 1
list[0] = 4
list[1] = 1
list[2] = 2
list[3] = 1
list[4] = 1
list[5] = 3
list[6] = 1
list[7] = 1
list[8] = 1
list[9] = 1
list3[3]=list1[1]+list2[4]
list3[3]=list1[2]+list2[1]
list3[3]=list1[3]+list2[2]
list3[3]=list1[4]+list2[1]
list3[3]=list1[1]+list2[1]
list3[3]=list1[2]+list2[3]
list3[3]=list1[3]+list2[1]
list3[3]=list1[1]+list2[1]
list3[3]=list1[41]+list2[1]
list3[3]=list1[2]+list2[1]
```

does anybody have an idea what should I do to make it work properly?

Comment: Hint : Check this line `sum = list1[i]+list2[i];`

Comment: ooh! thank you! i thought i had to use sum. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the values at each index and put them back in the list3.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what u want to achieve..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class fib{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    int list1[]=new int[10];
    int list2[]=new int[10];
    int list3[]=new int[10];
    int i, sum=0, num1=0, num2=0;
    String input=" ";

    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            list1[i]=0;
            list2[i]=0;
            list3[i]=0;
        }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.print("Input value for list1[" + i + "] = ");

            try{
                input=in.readLine();
            }catch(IOException e){}
            num1=Integer.parseInt(input);
            list1[i]=num1;
           }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "] = "+list1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.print("Input value for list2[" + i + "] = ");

            try{
                input=in.readLine();
            }catch(IOException e){}
            num2=Integer.parseInt(input);
            list2[i]=num2;
           }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "] = "+list2[i]);
    }    
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println( list1[i]+list2[i] + "="+"list1[" + list1[i] + "]+"+"list2[" + list2[i] + "]");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'sum' is not an array. Just a variable to store single value. You are adding each element of list 1 and list 2 but replacing in the variable 'sum'. Instead either make sum an array or use list 3 to store all the 10 values

```
int sum[] = new int[10];
sum[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
```

or

```
list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
```

Comment: thank you for explaining that! i need to read more on these stuff and not skim on them. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You've added list1 and list2 and stored it in sum but where did you store that sum in list3?  You need to store the sum of the two lists in the third list like this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    list3[i] = list1[i]+list2[i];
}
```

Then in the final println statement I'm not really sure what you're trying to show.  To show the list3 contents just repeat what you did before:

```
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("list[" + i + "] = "+list3[i]);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for elaborating, will improve on efficiency :)